# How to save record in db using ajax in extjs?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, extjs, extjs6

I have a list of items in view(js) which is ordered in row wise.I need to autosave the clicked rows details in db using ajax in extjs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a Ext.grid.Panel you could add an event listener on [rowclick](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#event-rowclick) on the panel itself and then there throwing the request. See [Ext.Ajax.request](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Ajax.html#method-request) method.

So in your ViewController you set the event:

`'rowclick': function(grid, record) {
      Ext.Ajax.request({
         url: '/your/url',
         method: 'POST',
         params: { id: record.get('id') } //or whatever you have in the record
      }).then(function(response) { 
         // whatever you want to do with the response
      });
}`

If your element is not a grid you will have another event attached to it, you can find it in the documentation